# Pull values from the JSON in order - first all the first character, then all the seconds and etc

Tags: python, loops

This is JSON:

```
    "y": {
        "titleOne": {
            "a": [{
                    "ss": "one"
                }, {
                    "ss": "two"
                }
            ]
        },
        "titleTwo": {
            "a": [{
                    "ss": "one"
                }, {
                    "ss": "two"
                }, {
                    "ss": "thee"
                }
            ]
        },
        ..........
```

This is my current code:

```
for i in y:
   for c in y[i]["a"]:
      print(c["ss"])
```

This code will simply print all values in order:

```
one
two
one
two
three
```

but I need that loop will get the first value from each section and will return

```
one
one
two
two
three
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: collect the values in a `list`, sort the `list` and then print it.

Comment: @quamrana I wish to, but I do not know how to construct it logically, you can explain how to do it logically ... it is all what I need

Comment: Well, just start from what you *know* you can do. So, could you just print out the first `'ss'` item from each list?

Comment: @Shiva I need to pick the first character from the array, then go to the next key and pick up the first one again up to the end, then come back and collect all the second elements from an array and continue....

Comment: @quamrana I have should some sample code to simply print the elements one by one in order.... but how to get the first element from array (from the first key) and then go to the next one and then come back the second element

Comment: @quamrana AH !!! Will try something

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is not a valid SO question. This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Write my program logic” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
y = {"titleOne": {"a": [{"ss": "one"}, {"ss": "two"}]},
     "titleTwo": {"a": [{"ss": "one"}, {"ss": "two"}, {"ss": "three"}]}}

#check the max depth you can go to
depth = max(len(y[title]["a"]) for title in y)
for i in range(depth):
    for title in y:
        if len(y[title]["a"])>i:
            print(y[title]["a"][i]["ss"])

one
one
two
two
three
```

Comment: This is much better than I have just tried :D .... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just for experimentation, you can give `zip_longest` a try. This code is not written not keeping in mind efficiency, ideally, generators can be used.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

d = {"y": {
    "titleOne": {
        "a": [{
                "ss": "one"
            }, {
                "ss": "two"
            }
        ]
    },
    "titleTwo": {
        "a": [{
                "ss": "one"
            }, {
                "ss": "two"
            }, {
                "ss": "thee"
            }
        ]
    }
}}
    
ll = [[k['ss'] for k in j] for j in [i['a'] for i in d['y'].values()]]

for i in zip_longest(*generators):
    print(*filter(bool, i))
```